# Defining a space in JQuery Form Validation regex expression

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am validating a form using jQuery form validation, one of the field needs to be four digits space four digits, e.g. `1234 5678`

I can get it to validate if I replace the space with a hyphen:

```
$.validator.addMethod("companynumber", function(value, element) {
var regexp = /^[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{4}$/;
var strippedValue = value.replace(/\s/g, '');
return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(strippedValue);
},  "Enter a valid Company Number.");
```

But cannot find what I need to put in the regex for a single space between the digit blocks, can anybody help please?

Comment: A space. `/^[0-9]{4} [0-9]{4}$/`. (Sometimes a thing can be so obvious we miss it ;-)

Comment: If somehow this regex is considered 'expanded', you have to escape the space ^[0-9]{4}\ [0-9]{4}$ or ^[0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}$, but I don't think thats the problem. I think there is a hyphen in what you're validating, otherwise it would not match (validate) right?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acheong87 is right that you can just get a space with `/^[0-9]{4} [0-9]{4}$/`, but it looks like you are also stripping out spaces before you check against the regex. If you want the regex to match properly you shouldn't be using `strippedValue` to do the regexp.test.

So something like this should work:

```
$.validator.addMethod("companynumber", function(value, element) {
var regexp = /^[0-9]{4} [0-9]{4}$/;
return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
},  "Enter a valid Company Number.");
```

Comment: I thought he said he could get it to validate with a hyphen.

Comment: Yes I did get it working with a hyphen - I just used a hyphen to check I was on th right lines. What I wasn't able to do was replace the hyphen with a space

Comment: Thanks Andy/Acheong87 - I'd totally overlooked the strippedvalue, as Acheong87 said it's easy to miss the obvious :)